# Creat Another Independent Powershell Script through first Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

So I wanted to know how to make powershell *Script A* can create powershell *Script B*

The main goal is to have *Script B* be independent of *Script A* (for security purposes). I have Keys that I get with *Script A* and hash them.

I want to also have Script A create *Script B*, as *Script B* will do an action and will also be taken to other separate environments.

So how can I:

**A:** Make the new script via the first?

**B:** Have, $hash1 (hash of key1), pass on to *Script B*, So that when *Script B* runs in a separate VM or PC environment, it does not require *Script A* to use $hash1

Thanks

Comment: So from what I can gather the goal is to have Script A generate Script B, which relies on a hash, but then somehow have Script B work without the hash being present?   That's not going to be workable, either the hash is there and can be used for auth by the script (and by extension anyone who has read access to the script) or the hash is not there and the script won't be able to auth.  on the other hand if your just looking to have Script A generate Script B with some unique hash you can do that with `Out-File` but anyone who has access to Script B will have access to your key(even if hashed).

Comment: Might be nice to know why you want to do this incase you have an XY problem on your hands. Perhaps knowing the real motivation for this would get you a better answer.

Comment: @Matt
in all actuality my goal was to end up making  a script that asks for a key via dialog, hashes it and creates a reusable exe file via ps1 script that activates windows, software etc.... I already made a script to do the latter manually... but no way to simplify the process to grandma level of just double-cicking a file, entering new key and generating a new exe based on it.

Answer (score 1):

A: Powershell script is saved as text. You (=script A) can print text into file (for example scriptB.ps) and this file can be executed.

B: You can use "return statement" in script A. And if you don't need this hash, so you have to write your code to run even without this input parameter or use default parameter. And how? With if statements probably.

Answer (score 1):

I created a tool that is like what you are describing except that it is more limited in scope, but perhaps more generic.  I actually created it not to generate powershell scripts but to generate SQL scripts.  I could use it to generate PS scripts, but of a very limited form,  which would look like this:

```
& someFunctionorApp -arg11 -arg12 -arg13 ...
& someFunctionorApp -arg21 -arg22 -arg23 ...
```

and repeated perhaps a hundred times.  The args all come from some data source or other, and I've just plugged generic names in for the sake of example.  This generated script might do by brute force something that a clever scripter would do inside a loop, but so be it.

For my tool,  the driver is data stored inside a CSV file.  I can get CSV files from databases, from spreadsheets,  and from simple PS scripts that capture information.  Different CSV files have different headers, with different field names, and so on.  The tool is generic.  The other input to my tool is what I have called a template.  A template, in this context, is just a text file with some embedded PS variables.  The tool runs through the CSV file picking up actual values to store in place of the PS variables.

The output comes out on the console, but it's easily redirected to a file.

Just for grins, I have included the tool.  If the tool is not to your liking, perhaps you can pick up a technique or two and adapt them.

```
<#  This function is a table driven template tool. 
    It's a refinement of an earlier attempt.

    It generates output from a template and
    a driver table.  The template file contains plain
    text and embedded variables.  The driver table 
    (in a csv file) has one column for each variable, 
    and one row for each expansion to be generated.

    5/13/2015

#>

function Expand-csv {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   Param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [string] $driver,
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [string] $template
   )
   Process
   {
      $OFS = "`r`n"
      $list = Import-Csv $driver
      [string]$pattern = Get-Content $template

      foreach ($item in $list) {
         foreach ($key in $item.psobject.properties) {
            Set-variable -name $key.name -value $key.value
            }
         $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($pattern) 
         }
   }
}
```